# Matt Galloway book EOC: delegate ignore protocol method

Tags: ios, delegates, runtime, protocols

Item 15 of Matt Galloway book EOC, an example is used to show potential name clash, which is completely understandable. But I am paying attention on the implementation of protocol method, it is not implemented...and no error/warning from the complier.

```
// EOCSoundPlayer.h file 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class EOCSoundPlayer;
@protocol EOCSoundPlayerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)soundPlayerDidFinish:(EOCSoundPlayer*)player;
@end

@interface EOCSoundPlayer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <EOCSoundPlayerDelegate> delegate;
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url;
- (void)playSound;
@end

// EOCSoundPlayer.m file 
#import "EOCSoundPlayer.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

void completion(SystemSoundID ssID, void *clientData) {
    EOCSoundPlayer *player = (__bridge EOCSoundPlayer*)clientData;
    if ([player.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(soundPlayerDidFinish:)]) {
        [player.delegate soundPlayerDidFinish:player];
    }
}

@implementation EOCSoundPlayer {
    SystemSoundID _systemSoundID;
}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &_systemSoundID);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(_systemSoundID);
}

- (void)playSound {
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(
                                          _systemSoundID,
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL,
                                          completion,
                                          (__bridge void*)self);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_systemSoundID);
}

@end
```

Why is there NO implementation of protocol method "soundPlayerDidFinish:" in the .m file? Is it unnecessary to do in custom code, if so, what is the default implementation? Will it have to be implemented at run-time at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound player doesn't implement the protocol it self, it has a delegate which implements the protocol. After all, it's the `EOCSoundPlayerDelegate` protocol.

It is a very to have a delegate that conforms to a custom protocol like in that example. It leads to a nice loose coupling. The sound player only intends to call certain methods (only one method in this case) on its delegate, so it only matters that the delegate implements those methods (that method in this case).

You will also see that the sound player checks before invoking the method on the delegate that the delegate also responds to that method.

Comment: You are right. EOCSoundPlayer class does not claim to be the delegate, only its property @property (nonatomic, weak) id <EOCSoundPlayerDelegate> delegate; claim to do the delegation. My tired eyes messed up. Thanks!